Setting up Prometheus and Jaeger with docker-compose
I have successfully integrated Prometheus into my monitoring workflow, monitoring my grpc services. But Jaeger is missing and tbh I have no idea what I could be missing.
This is my otel-collector config
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
processors:
extensions:
  health_check: {}

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: jaeger:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  prometheus:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:9090
    namespace: testapp
  debug:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [otlp, debug]

    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [prometheus, debug]


For reference this is my working prometheus:
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'kirk-grpc-service-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['otel-collector:9090']

  - job_name: "http-fitme-dev"
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8001']

The idea here was to have my grpc services running on port 8000 and my metrics server through http on port 8001/metrics.
Alright so My gRPC server expects to receive a prometheus registry (works) and a trace provider:
traceProvider, err := grpcprometheus.SetupTracing(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to configure OpenTelemetry trace provider")
    }


server, listener, err := grpc.BootstrapServer(port, log, reg, traceProvider)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to configure gRPC server")
    }

On the server part I bootstrap all the necessary middleware:
func BootstrapServer(
  port string,
  log *zap.Logger,
  registry *prometheus.Registry,
  traceProvider trace.TracerProvider,
  opts ...grpc.ServerOption,
) (*grpc.Server, net.Listener, error) {
  // setup basic metrics

  // initiate the listener
  listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port))
  if err != nil {
   return nil, nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to create listener")
  }

  // -- Prometheus interceptor Setup
  promCollectors := grpcprometheus.NewPrometheusMetricsCollectors()
  // Must be called before using Prometheus interceptors
  err = grpcprometheus.RegisterMetrics(registry, promCollectors)
  _, promInterceptor, err := grpcprometheus.Interceptors(promCollectors)
  if err != nil {
   return nil, nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to create Prometheus interceptors")
  }

  // -- OpenTelemetry interceptor setup
  otel.SetTracerProvider(traceProvider)
  otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(
   propagation.TraceContext{},
   propagation.Baggage{},
  ))

  _, spanInterceptor := grpcspan.Interceptors()
  _, serverInterceptor, _ := grpcprometheus.Interceptors(promCollectors)
  // -- Zap logging interceptor setup
  _, logInterceptor := grpclog.Interceptors(log)
  // -- Recovery interceptor setup
  _, recoveryInterceptor := grpcrecovery.Interceptors(grpcrecovery.RegisterMetrics(registry))
  // session
  sessionInterceptor := session.InterceptorSession()
  requestGeneratorSession := grpcrequest.RequestIDMiddleware()

  // Configure server options from our base configuration
  serverOptions := []grpc.ServerOption{
   grpc.KeepaliveEnforcementPolicy(middleware.KeepaliveEnforcementPolicy()),
   grpc.KeepaliveParams(middleware.KeepAliveServerParams()),

   // Note: Order of interceptors for the connection matters.
   // Trace interceptor must be the first interceptor in the chain for cross-service spans
   // to work correctly as it needs the original inbound context.

   // Add the unary interceptors
   grpc.ChainUnaryInterceptor(
    spanInterceptor.Unary,
    promInterceptor.Unary,
    serverInterceptor.Unary,
    logInterceptor.Unary,
    sessionInterceptor,
    requestGeneratorSession,
    recoveryInterceptor.Unary,
   ),

   //grpc.StatsHandler(otelgrpc.NewServerHandler()),

   // Add the stream interceptors
   grpc.ChainStreamInterceptor(
    spanInterceptor.Stream,
    promInterceptor.Stream,
    serverInterceptor.Stream,
    logInterceptor.Stream,
    recoveryInterceptor.Stream,
    recoveryInterceptor.Stream,
   ),
  }

  // Append any additional options passed in while connecting
  serverOptions = append(serverOptions, opts...)

  server := grpc.NewServer(serverOptions...)

  return server, listener, nil
}

having my trace provider. Here is how I setup the trace provider:
func SetupTracing(ctx context.Context) (*trace.TracerProvider, error) {
    tp, err := otelTraceProvider(ctx, "http://otel-collector:4317", "", "", true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create trace provider: %w", err)
    }

    return tp, nil
}

func otelTraceProvider(ctx context.Context, endpoint, apiKey, caCertPath string, insecure bool) (*trace.TracerProvider, error) {
    var opts []otlptracegrpc.Option

    // Set endpoint
    opts = append(opts, otlptracegrpc.WithEndpoint(endpoint))
    opts = append(opts, otlptracegrpc.WithInsecure())

    // Handle insecure or TLS configuration
    if insecure {
        opts = append(opts, otlptracegrpc.WithInsecure())
    } else {
        c, err := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(caCertPath, "")
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create TLS credentials: %w", err)
        }
        opts = append(opts, otlptracegrpc.WithTLSCredentials(c))
    }

    // Add authorization header if needed (uncomment if using API keys)
    // opts = append(opts, otlptracegrpc.WithHeaders(map[string]string{
    //     "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
    // }))

    exp, err := otlptracegrpc.New(ctx, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create OTLP trace exporter: %w", err)
    }

    res := resource.NewWithAttributes(
        semconv.SchemaURL,
        semconv.ServiceNameKey.String("FITDEV"),
        semconv.ServiceNamespaceKey.String("FitME"),
        semconv.ServiceVersionKey.String("0.1"),
        semconv.DeploymentEnvironmentKey.String("production"),
    )

    tp := trace.NewTracerProvider(
        trace.WithBatcher(exp),
        trace.WithResource(res),
    )

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)

    return tp, nil
}

Anyone knows what I could be missing ? I want to move on with this but settings up jaeger has put me in the dark since it seems I have everything necessary except probably one port or endpoint. Im totally blind on this one.

Your question is not a minimal repro and it doesn't clearly define a question; what does "Jaeger is missing" mean? Your code is snippets. You don't include the Docker Compose file that you're using. Unless someone is very familiar with your configuration and intent, your question will struggle to be answered and there's little benefit to others from its existence. A minimal repro would pare everything back to the issue presumably related to integrating Jaeger through an OpenTelemetry collector with Go!?
